# grads.grad give me None

Tags: optimization

I have Graph Classification and the weight are self.W

```
print("self.W" ,self.W)

        # output:
        {'pre.0.weight': Parameter containing:
tensor([[-3.5673e-01, -9.4013e-03, -2.0755e-01,  1.4225e-01, -3.2211e-01,
          2.7680e-01, -2.7478e-01],
        ...,
        [ 7.5832e-01, -5.8722e-02,  2.5054e-01, -2.6951e-01, -7.0048e-03,
         -1.7488e-03, -1.0929e-01],
        [ 4.4762e-01, -2.1975e-01, -3.4676e-01,  5.2748e-02, -2.8744e-01,
          1.5820e-01, -3.0140e-01]], requires_grad=True), 'pre.0.bias': Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.5400, -0.1962, -0.4119, -0.5536,  0.4469,  0.2122,  0.1987,  0.5821,
        -0.3217,  0.5140, -0.3519,  0.4148,  0.3902, -0.3033,  0.0547, -0.2928,
        -0.4317, -0.6072, -0.2308,  0.4828,  0.4573,  0.8742,  0.2621,  0.0591],
       requires_grad=True), 'graph_convs.0.nn.0.weight': Parameter containing:
tensor([[-2.0728e-01, -6.0267e-02, -1.8664e-01,  ...,  2.8053e-01,
          1.4203e-02,  1.4953e-01],
        [-1.1624e-01, -1.0842e-01, -1.5145e-01,  ...,  1.4988e-01,
          6.7796e-02,  1.1209e-01],
        ...,

        [ 6.5656e-02,  8.9351e-02, -6.4037e-02,  ..., -4.0376e-02,
         -4.9346e-02,  2.1752e-02]], requires_grad=True), 'graph_convs.0.nn.0.bias': Parameter containing:
tensor([ 0.1731,  0.0996,  0.1668, -0.0068,  0.0853,  0.0340, -0.0568, -0.0725,
         0.0470,  0.1446, -0.1210,  0.0610, -0.1211, -0.1013, -0.1087,  0.0543,
        -0.0399, -0.0667,  0.0572,  0.0774,  0.1090, -0.0927,  0.1276, -0.1017],
       requires_grad=True), 'graph_convs.0.nn.2.weight': Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.0402,  0.0856,  0.0054,  ...,  0.0685, -0.1084, -0.0698],
        [ 0.1971,  0.1014,  0.2685,  ..., -0.0710,  0.0326, -0.0760],
        ...,
        [-0.0012,  0.0157,  0.1059,  ...,  0.0677,  0.1579, -0.0479],
        [ 0.1209, -0.1055,  0.0495,  ...,  0.0790, -0.0415, -0.0381]]
```

and now  when I want to grad it it gives me None

```
grads = {key: value.grad for key, value in self.W.items()}
print("grads \n " ,grads )
# outputs:

grads
  {'pre.0.weight': None, 'pre.0.bias': None, 'graph_convs.0.nn.0.weight': None, 'graph_convs.0.nn.0.bias': None, 'graph_convs.0.nn.2.weight': None, 'graph_convs.0.nn.2.bias': None, 'graph_convs.1.nn.0.weight': None, 'graph_convs.1.nn.0.bias': None, 'graph_convs.1.nn.2.weight': 
None, 'graph_convs.1.nn.2.bias': None, 'graph_convs.2.nn.0.weight': None, 'graph_convs.2.nn.0.bias': None, 'graph_convs.2.nn.2.weight': None, 'graph_convs.2.nn.2.bias': None, 'post.0.weight': None, 'post.0.bias': None, 'readout.0.weight': None, 'readout.0.bias': None}
```

any Idea?

at fist I thouth Autograd is Disabled and i changed the code to this:

```
        with torch.enable_grad():
          grads = {key: value.grad for key, value in new_w.items()}
```

but it wasn't the solution

another thing I saw in internt that used is_leaf to see its True or False
I use it and got True
I don't know what should I try next